# Sort NSArray with specific order

Tags: nsarray

I have an Array with some String objects lets say months.

[October] [May] [July] [January] [August]

and I want to sort it:

[January] [May] [July] [August] [October]

is there a smart way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific logic in the NSString by then selfs, to achieve the kind of sorting you want. You could have, instead of NSString, NSDictionaries. With keys according to the order you want, for example:

1 - January
5 - May
7 - July

You could then re-order using the key.